# Module not found error in python while importing from another file?

Tags: python

I am getting module not found error when I am importing another python file.

Here is the code of the file which I am importing

```
import mysql.connector

mysql = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user = "root", passwd = "#####" , database = "trading")
aa = mysql.cursor()
insert_into_table='insert into ticks(last_price,date) values(%(last_price)s,%(date)s)'
def insert_ticks(ticks):
    c=mysql.cursor()
    for tick in ticks:
        c.execute(insert_into_table,{'last_price':tick['last_price'],
                                    'date':tick['timestamp']})
    try:
        db.commit()
    except Exception:
        db.rollback()
```

I named this file as `py_mysql`. Now when I am importing this file to another code. It is giving an error that module not found.
I ran `sys` and `sys.path` too.

```
['C:\\Users\\ADMIN',
 'c:\\users\\admin\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\python37.zip',
 'c:\\users\\admin\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\DLLs',
 'c:\\users\\admin\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib',
 'c:\\users\\admin\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37',
 '',
 'c:\\users\\admin\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib\\site-packages',
 'c:\\users\\admin\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib\\site-packages\\kiteconnect-3.8.0-py3.7.egg',
 'c:\\users\\admin\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'c:\\users\\admin\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'c:\\users\\admin\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
 'c:\\users\\admin\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions',
 'C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\.ipython']
```

I have placed my py_mysql file in `C:\\Users\\ADMIN` location. 
Here is the error that I am getting

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-0da7c671bbff> in <module>
      1 # import sys
      2 # sys.path
----> 3 from py_mysql import *
      4 from kiteconnect import KiteConnect
      5 from kiteconnect import KiteTicker

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'py_mysql'
```

Kindly suggest what can be done to resolve this ?

Comment: Paste the error message, it might even be a problem inside the py_mysql file

Comment: Can you disclose,  what you are trying to import

Comment: Check whether `import py_mysql` gives the same error or not. Also I suggest that you place an empty file named `__init__.py` in the same folder that contains `py_mysql.py`

Comment: @leqo Just to correct, the empty file should be named ```__init__.py``` and not ```__init.py__```

Comment: @KarthickMohanraj yeah thanks, I already corrected it

Comment: Tried all the suggestions but none of them worked

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your file is named `py_mysql.py`.

Your python may be called with `py`, `py3`, `python` or `python3`. Here I will be using `python3`.

Make sure your `py_mysql.py` is located in one of the folders listed in `python3 -m site` (input command in terminal).

You should no longer get the error `ModuleNotFoundError` when running `python3 -c 'import py_mysql'` from the terminal.

If you are getting the error when running it from your IDE your project interpreter may be using a different Python interpreter. Make sure the path match `which python3` on Linux and `where python3` on Windows.

Comment: Well. My file name was py_mysql.ipynb and not python py_mysql.py. After changing it to py, the error has changed to NameError 
NameError: name 'null' is not defined

Comment: That's a new error unrelated to `ModuleNotFoundError`. Close this question and create a new question. Include the code and traceback error in your next question.